# Unable to find openxml sdk productivity tool

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I had the openxml sdk productivity tool on my machine but it got uninstalled. Now I cannot seem to find the setup anywhere on Microsoft's site.
has it been discontinued?

Comment: in case it has been discontinued, how can i use openxml to generate a powerpoint programatically?

Comment: same issue here, any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

### [DocXToSource](https://github.com/rmboggs/DocxToSource#docxtosource)

If you go to Microsoft's [OpenXML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) page on github, near the bottom there is a link inside the Related Tools section, to [DocxToSource](https://github.com/rmboggs/DocxToSource) and in the comments it says:

> This is a tool designed to be a replacement for the old OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool.

I have not tried it yet, but the screenshots on the home page look encouraging.

A note in the top paragraph of the project says:  *This is still a work in progress.*

Answer (score 1):

I found it here:
https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5

(OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi file apparently added to Github a few months after the original post.)

:o)